# How to change color of only text of anchor link?

Tags: css, hover

I have code like this

```
<a href="#" title="some title">
  <span>Do not change color of this text</span>
  Want to only change this text color
</a>
```

I want to change the color of anchor tag text only, not color of text in `span`.
Using CSS not jQuery.

Comment: use a{color:blue;} and a span{color:black;}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a style to ensure the correct colors are being applied:

```
a {
    color: #00f;
}
p, a span {
    color: #000;
}
```

This sets the color of normal text (`p`) and spans inside links (`a span`) to black, whereas it sets the color of the rest of the text in links to blue.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to apply two styles - one to your a tag and one to your span tag:

```
a {color:#000000; /*new colour*/}
a span {color:#aaaaaa; /*originalcolour*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a CSS for the anchors.
Why not create a second CSS for the span within the anchor?

```
a span {color:#000000;}
```

Comment: .a the link is not a class